# new line as delimiter in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, jython

I want to read a csv file till it finds a empty/new line
I am using END as a delimiter, want to change it to new/empty line

```
 def getActualData(ws_name, ws_value):

    outputDatafile = open('D:\\Files\\Actual_Data.csv', 'r',newline="\n")
    outputReader = csv.reader(outputDatafile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    outputData = {}
    check =0

    for rows in outputReader:
        #print "Row first:", rows[0]," Row second:",rows[1]
        if(check==0):    
            if(rows[0]==ws_name and rows[1]==ws_value):
                check+=1
        elif (rows[0]=='\n' and rows[1]=='\n'):
            break
        else:
            outputData.update({rows[0]:rows[1]})
```

Comment: How do you handle a totally valid csv where quote chars can encapsulate a newline before the end of the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the length of rows is 0, it means empty line. and you should check empty line first. otherwise, rows[0] can make exception.

```
if (len(rows)==0):
    break    
elif(check==0):
    if(rows[0]==ws_name and rows[1]==ws_value):
        check+=1
else:
    outputData.update({rows[0]:rows[1]})
```

Comment: if my output file is like:
Name 1,Addition
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4

Name 2,multiplication
aa,11
bb,22
cc,33
dd,44

Name 3,Addition
a,13
b,23
c,33
d,43

This way it does not read name 3

Comment: @user2822809 would you update your question? comment can't show multi line text.